# Start VBA macros by open Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

How can I start a macro by opening an Excelsheet. I have already put this code:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Tabelle1.ListBox1

    .AddItem "TEST1"
    .AddItem "TEST2"
    .AddItem "TEST3"
End With

With Tabelle1.ListBox2

    .AddItem "TEST4"
    .AddItem "TEST5"
End With    

With Tabelle1.ListBox1
    .Width = 140.25
    .Height = 255.25

End With
With Tabelle1.ListBox2
    .Width = 78
    .Height = 69.75    
End With

Call EnterInDesignMode
Call ExitInDesignMode
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Into `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. But it doesn't go to the second Code.
What am I doing wrong here?

Both Codes are above the `Public Sub Workbook_Open()`

```
'first Code
    Sub EnterInDesignMode()
        With Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1605)
            .Execute
        End With
    End Sub

'Second Code
Sub ExitInDesignMode()
    Dim sTemp As String
    With Application.CommandBars("Exit Design Mode")
        sTemp = .Controls(1).Caption
    End With
End Sub
```

Both codes are working, but it doesn't stops the call `EnterInDesignMode()`, so it doesn't call the `ExitInDesignMode()`.

Comment: can we see your workbook_open sub?

Comment: Did you read this: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155#bmrunmacroautomatically    It tells you were to put the workbook_open sub. It should NOT be in a module.

Comment: @99moorem i have edited the thread. You should now be able to see it.

Comment: @Luuklag no i have put it above the Private Sub Workbook_open(), to call it but it only calls the EnterInDesignMode() and not the ExitInDesignMode()

Comment: What code do you want it to run? A different sub?

Comment: what happens in EnterInDesignMode sub?

Comment: @Luuklag i want to run the EnterInDesignMode() at first, and the ExitInDesignMode() thereafter.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/XN27a-Gxz6g perhaps this is of help

Comment: @MissPalmer it enters the DesignMode in Excel, theres a Bug in Excel with Listboxes. It doesnt resize it.

Here a Picture
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=051006-1438078449.jpg

But if i start the DesignMode it actually "resize" the Listbox

Comment: @Luuklag its only calls the EnterInDesignMode(), but then it doesnt calls the ExitInDesignMode. If you try it in VBA mit F8 you will see it doesnt stops that call...

Comment: First of all: there should be an "End With" after Table1Listbox2

Comment: Ah I see. Once it opens the designmode, it also does this for the code editor, so you are no longer running the code but editing it. Perhaps you need to close the code editer and try again.

Comment: @Luuklag What do you mean? Youre right, it opens the DesignMode but it doesnt Close it. Do you have any suggestions, how can i Bypass this problem?

Comment: The problem is that opening the design mode stops the code from running. So my best guess would be to code something that happens on the event "entering design mode"

Comment: @Luuklag thank you, but i have no idea how i can programm this :S Does anybody have an Solution for that?

Comment: Code doesn't run in design mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With CommandBars("Exit Design Mode").Controls(1)
    If .State = msoButtonDown Then .Execute
 End With
```

Edit the code you have to this, as is posted in the link I commented with.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/XN27a-Gxz6g